# Size element so it is exactly as tall as it needs to be to not scroll

Tags: javascript, css, extjs, sencha-touch

Size element so it is exactly as tall as it needs to be to not scroll
I am working on a tool to allow creating small "notes" that I then turn into `Ext.Draggable` items. What I would like to do is to have these items be sized no taller than they need to be.

The elements are absolutely positioned: set `position: absolute` with `top` and `left` and `height` and `width` values in-line. The problem is that the height values are not really very reliable.

Is it possible to set the size at something very short (say 3px), then increment the height until the scrollbars disappear? How can I tell when that occurs, and can I do it in a way that's reliable across browsers?

[Code: http://github.com/artlung/ArtLung-Notes/blob/master/v2/index.js](http://github.com/artlung/ArtLung-Notes/blob/master/v2/index.js)

Comment: Also, it's in ExtJS's new Sencha framework, which uses ExtJS under the hood, but if there's a universal DOM solution to this, that'd be great. Also would be interested in other implementations (jQuery, Prototype, MooTools) that I can learn from and modify.

Comment: Won't simply removing explicit height do what you want?  (I know Ext generally sucks for autosizing and I have to struggle every time I need it in another instance though.)

Comment: That seems so simple. For some reason I thought I needed to put heights on the elements when I created them. That seems to be working in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari, which is an excellent sign!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, see `Ext.util.TextMetrics.getHeight()`.  Note that you can't use the singleton for height determination.

However, I think that removing explicit height should generally solve your problem.  That's unless you need to synchronize something like shadow overlay's size, though.

Comment: Thanks for the referral to `Ext.util.TextMetrics` - I'll be looking at that one in the future. Sometimes it's the simple solutions that are best.

Answer (score 1):

If an element's style.position is absolute and the style.width is determined, setting its style.height to 'auto' will make a containing box for its content and padding, with no scrollbars.

Comment: It looks like `auto` is the default value http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property